# How do I change height of header size and make the images appear

Tags: digital-experience, header, height

How do I change the default header height of the Salesforce Customer Service Experience Cloud theme? I see the option to change color or add an image (for the Header), but there is not an option to change the size.
Then, how do I change the permissions so public can view the whole page of site. Currently the 3 images in the center are not shown. [See Website](https://playful-moose-lq7u68-dev-ed.trailblaze.my.site.com/s)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adjust the height by using the controls in the component settings menu (this appears when you click on the component in the experience builder. See this article for examples:

- [Theme Guidance: Header Components](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_theme-g-header.htm&type=5)

To make your site publicly available check the box next to the label "Public Access" in the general tab of the experience builder settings menu.

If you are having trouble with images not appearing when viewing the site as a user you may need to use a relative url in the image source or create a public url for the file:

- [Images Saved as Static Resources Don't Display on the Experience Cloud Site](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387235&type=1)
- [Create and Share a Public Link for a Folder in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_sharing_via_link.htm&type=5#:%7E:text=Create%20and%20Share%20a%20Public%20Link%20for%20a%20Folder%20in%20Lightning%20Experience)